# How to load image data from bcf files in Adobe VFR dataset mentioned in deepfont paper?

Tags: python, image, computer-vision, ocr

I'm writing my implementation of deepfont(https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.03196.pdf). The authors made the data(AdobeVFR data) public on which the model was trained. The images are in bcf format. How can I load image data from bcf files?

Answer (score 0):

The main publisher of DeepFont, [Dr. Atlas Wang](https://www.atlaswang.com/home), provides a [link](https://www.atlaswang.com/resource) for the dataset to [a Google Drive folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VJ8rlmxWjS2Xv0eFECfpRuNWuRrqh6h6) which contains the raw images as well. Instead of extracting the images from BCF format, you could download them directly from there.